# Rails admin with Sorcery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin, sorcery

I'm trying to install the [Rails Admin Gem](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) using [Sorcery](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery) for authentication instead of Devise.

Rails admin does provide a hook that you can use to attach your own authentication method. [Here](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Authentication) is the example they provide in their docs (using warden):

```
config.authenticate_with do
  warden.authenticate! :scope => :admin
end
config.current_user_method { current_admin }
```

I'm guessing that inside the block I need to reference the `before_filter` that Sorcery uses to authenticate users, which would be [`require_login`](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/blob/master/lib/sorcery/controller.rb#L22).

However, when I try that and I try to visit `/admin` when logged out, I get a routing error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"sessions"}
```

This probably happens because I am being redirected within the engine rather than in the main app.

How can I set this up correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
# config/initializers/rails_admin.rb
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.authenticate_with do
    # Use sorcery's before filter to auth users
    require_login
  end
end

# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController
  # Overwrite the method sorcery calls when it
  # detects a non-authenticated request.
  def not_authenticated
    # Make sure that we reference the route from the main app.
    redirect_to main_app.login_path
  end
end

#config/initializers/rails_admin.rb
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  ...
  config.parent_controller = 'ApplicationController'
end
```

Comment: This does not work for me. I am getting this error: ```undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<RailsAdmin::MainController```.   I am overriding the ```not_authenticated``` action using your suggested code, and it is does override for calls made in my app, but it does not seem to override for the calls made by rails_admin.

Comment: It was because my app did not have ```config.parent_controller = 'ApplicationController'``` in the rails_admin initialisation file. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Sorcery with *Cancancan* gem, you should also add `config.current_user_method(&:current_user)` in your `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb` file, or you'll get the error: `You are not authorized`.